# Opentok's preferredResolution for subscriber doen't work

Tags: webrtc, opentok, tokbox

I create opentok sessions on backend using `MediaMode.ROUTED` and create publisher object like this:

```
var publisherOptions =  {
    resolution: '1280x960',
    style: {
        nameDisplayMode: "on",
        buttonDisplayMode: "off"
    },
};
const el = createElement();
publisher = OT.initPublisher(el, publisherOptions);
```

On the subscriber end I connect like this:

```
subscriberOptions = {
    insertMode: 'append',
    preferredResolution: {width: 320, height: 240},
    style: {
        buttonDisplayMode: 'off'
    }
};
subscriber = session.subscribe(event.stream, 'subscriber', subscriberOptions, function(error) {
     if (error) {
     console.log('There was an error publishing: ', error.name, error.message);
     }
 });
```

But the stream I recieve on subscriber is `1280x960`, should'nt it be `320x240`?

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

The implementation looks correct, but please keep in mind that you can only control the resolution as the subscriber if the session is using [Scalable Video](https://support.tokbox.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001948650-TokBox-Scalable-Video-Simulcast-FAQ). Setting the preferred resolution will only work for streams published by clients that support scalable video: clients that use the OpenTok iOS SDK (on certain devices), the OpenTok Android SDK (on certain devices), or OpenTok.js in Chrome.
In streams that do not use scalable video, setting this property has no effect.

Please also keep in mind that not every resolution is available to a subscriber. When you set the preferred resolution, OpenTok.js and the video encoder pick the best resolution available that matches your setting. The resolutions available depend on the resolution of the published stream. The Subscriber object's `stream.resolution` property represents the highest resolution available for the stream. Each of the resolutions available for a stream will use the same aspect ratio. The actual resolutions available depend, dynamically, on network and CPU resources available to the publisher and subscriber.

For more information, please check out the [documentation](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Session.html#subscribe) for subscribring.

Comment: Lets consider a publisher is publishing 1280x960 and viewer's connection drops from 4G to 2G, ideally I want to be able to get least video resolution possible than hanging the video for a few seconds. How can I accomplish this? Right now opentok retains the resolution and decreases framerate. How can lower the vieo resolution and create a blurred video?

Comment: Are you using relayed or routed session also do you have VP8 set as your preferred codec? Scalable Video will only work in "routed" sessions with VP8 set as the preferred codec.

Comment: @AdamUllman,
1. I've set session as routed `MediaMode.ROUTED`.
2. My preferred codec is `VP8`.
3. My prefered resolution ```subscriber.setPreferredResolution({
                width: 10, height: 10,
            });``` But the video still has good clarity. I'm expecting a pixelated video.
If I set `preferredResolution` shouldn't the video be pixelated?

Comment: When you set the preferred resolution to be that low it will choose the lowest available resolution which will be minimum 320x240. This will appear pixelated if you display it at a larger size than that but if you're only displaying it at a small size then it will look fine.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I've set the preferred resolution to be really low but it's still coming back with videoDimensions as 720p. I know the device is capable of scalable video, and I know my api key has scalable video turned on. Why isn't it decreasing the videoDimensions?